# Threads and synchronisation

Tags: java, thread-safety

I've problem understanding the following piece of code:-

```
public class SoCalledSigleton{

    private final static boolean allDataLoaded = SoCalledSigleton();

    private SoCalledSigleton(){

         loadDataFromDB();
         loadDataFromFile();
         loadDataAgainFromDB();

    }    
}
```

Is this piece of code thread safe? If not then Why?

Answer (score 5):

This will create an error in Java.

```
private final static boolean allDataLoaded = SoCalledSigleton();
```

- You're assigning an object to a boolean variable.
- You forgot to add `new` to instantiate the variable.

But if your code is like this

```
 public class SoCalledSigleton{

    private final static SoCalledSigleton allDataLoaded = new SoCalledSigleton();

    private SoCalledSigleton(){

         loadDataFromDB();
         loadDataFromFile();
         loadDataAgainFromDB();

    }    
}
```

It is thread-safe as static initialization and static attributes are thread-safe. They are initialized only once and exists throughout the whole life-cycle of the system.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice that!

Comment: "[...] static attributes are thread-safe." This is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

(I assume that `allDataLoaded` is meant to be a `SoCalledSigleton` and `boolean` is just a typo :-)

If the class has no other constructors, or the `loadData*` methods don't do funny business (such as publishing `this`), its initialization is thread safe, because the initialization of final static data members is guarded by the JVM. Such members are initialized by the class loader when the class is first loaded. During this, there is a lock on the class so the initialization process is thread safe even if multiple threads try to access the class in parallel. So the constructor of the class is guaranteed to be called only once (per classloader - thanks Visage for the clarification :-).

Note that since you don't show us the rest of the class (I suppose it should have at least a `static getInstance` method, and probably further nonstatic members), we can't say anything about whether the whole implementation of the class is thread safe or not.

Comment: ...only once *per classloader*

Comment: Still one problem, there's no `new` keyword to instantiate the variable.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, you are right. Still, I believe all of us can see what the OP _meant_ to write :-)

Comment: @Péter Török, True... I'm just merely exposing the fact that the extensive use of IDE's has almost blinded us to do peer reviews to simple code....

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, I would not blame the IDEs, IMO it is rather a question of selective attention. I was focusing entirely on the concurrency aspects of the code, and once I recognized the pattern of Singleton, I saw what _should_ be there rather than what really was. Not to mention the mental pressure to produce answers fast... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The code is unusable in its current form, so any notions of thread safety are irrelevent.

What public interface would users use to get an instance of the singleton?

Comment: How about `class.forInstance("SoCalledSingleton")`? Or `SoCalledSingleton.class` ?

Comment: @Carl, that won't work since the constructor is private, so there won't be a reflective `newInstance()` to a private constructor.

Comment: @TEG: I tested: `class.forInstance()` works fine: I'm not calling the constructor, the classloader is, as part of static init. Method 2, mentioning the class, returns the class but doesn't cause initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's thread safe. The "method" is the constructor, and it will be called when the class is loaded, i.e. exactly once.

But looking at the stuff being done, I think it's probably a lousy idea to call it from the class loader. Essentially, you'll end up doing your DB connection and stuff at the point in time when something in your code touches the `SoCalledSingleton`. Chances are, this will not be inside some well-defined sequence of events where, if there's an error you have `catch` blocks to take you to some helpful GUI message handling or whatever.

The "cleaner" way is to use a `synchronized` `static getInstance()` method, which will construct your class and call its code exactly when `getInstance()` is called the first time.

**EDIT:** As The Elite Gentleman pointed out, there's a syntax error in there. You need to say

```
private final static SoCalledSingleton allDataLoaded = new SoCalledSigleton();
```

Comment: @Carl, add the `new` keyword to instantiate `allDataLoaded`.

Comment: Sorry.. The good peice of the code is 

public class SoCalledSigleton{

    private final static SoCalledSigleton allDataLoaded = new SoCalledSigleton();

    private SoCalledSigleton(){

         loadDataFromDB();
         loadDataFromFile();
         loadDataAgainFromDB();

    }    
}


boolean was just an typo..But what I'm not very sure about since the constructor is executing a lot of processes, it may so happen that another thread may start executing parallely

Comment: @Nirmalya: Well, that constructor will only run once regardless of what the other threads are doing, and how long that construction takes.

Answer (score 0):

**From what we can see**, there are no specific issues - it's guaranteed that the constructor will only ever by called once (so by definition can't be run multithreaded), which I presume is what you were concerned about.

However, there are still possible areas for problems.   Firstly, if the `loadData...` methods are public, then they can be called by anyone at any time, and quite possibly could lead to concurrency errors.

Additionally, these methods are presumably modifying some kind of collection somewhere.  If these collections are publically accessible before the constructor returns, then you can quite easily run into concurrency issues again.  This could be an issue with anything exception updating *instance-specific* fields (static fields may or may not exhibit this problem depending where they are defined in the file).

Depending on the way the class is used, simply *writing* all of the data single-threaded may not be good enough.  Collection classes are not necessarily safe for multi-threaded access even if read-only, so you'll need to ensure you're using the thread-safe data structures if multiple threads might access your singleton.

There are possibly other issues too.  Thread-safety isn't a simple check-list; you need to think about what bits of code/data might be accessed concurrently, and *ensure* that appropriate action is taken (declaring methods `synchronized`, using concurrent collections, etc.).  Thread-safety also isn't a binary thing (i.e. there's no such thing as "thread safe" per se); it depends how many threads will be accessing the class at once, what combinations of methods are thread-safe, whether sequences of operations will continue to function as one would expect (you can make a class "thread safe" in that is doesn't crash, but certain return values are undefined if pre-empted), what monitors threads need to hold to guarantee certain invariants etc.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that you need to think about and understand how the class is used.  Showing people a snapshot of half a file (which doesn't even compile), and asking them to give a yes/no answer, is not going to be beneficial.  At best they'll point out *some* of the issues for you if there are any; at worst you'll get a false sense of confidence.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.. You are right in saying that four lines of code does not mean anything. But my concern was from the very first view and making the simpliest of assumptions is it possible in any case that this class cannot qualify as a singleton in a multithreaded environment. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing anything.